# Using the word “droughts" after it has rained

Tags: grammar, past-vs-past-perfect, time-words

Since it rained today, then it will no longer be drought. So it is correct to use:

> It had been droughts for days and finally it rained today.

or should I put it in:

> It has been droughts for days

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is idiomatic English.

Even though we use word “it” for many weather-related sentences (e.g., “It has been sunny” or, “It has been dry” or, “It will be hot tomorrow"), we don’t typically use the “dummy it” with the word *drought*.

Also, I usually hear *drought* in the singular, unless we are talking about more than one drought (as in, “Last year, Iowa had droughts in April and in August.”)

So, instead of what you wrote, most native speakers would say something more like this:

> There had been a drought for days and it finally rained today.

or:

> We've had a drought for days but today it rained. Now the drought is finally over.